# Помогите, пожалуйста с запросом sql. Необходимо добавить к выборке текущий статус заявки

Tags: sql, sql-server

Помогите, пожалуйста, с запросом, хочу выбрать данные по каждой заявке (ремонтируемая техника, клиент, исполнитель работ-сотрудник сервисного центра, дата приема, текущий статус), но никак не могу понять, как к выборке добавить столбец с текущим статусом по каждой заявке, который определяется по одной последней дате заявки. Сделала вот такой запрос с группировкой, получила две группы (всего две заявки), получила дату приема заявки, как минимальную, но не могу для каждой заявки добавить текущий статус... Пробовала всячески группировать, делала подзапросы, но результат не тот. Использую СУБД MSSQL [image: Запрос]

Статусы хранятся в таблице Выполнение:[image: Таблица Выполнение]

То есть текущий статус заявки номер один будет под кодом 3 по дате 2021-11-20, а заявки 2 будет статус номер 5 по дате 2021-11-12. То есть хочу получить данные по заявкам: оборудование, клиент, сотрудник, дата приема + текущий статус (Для заявки 1 это будет статус Ремонт не возможен, а для заявки 2 будет статус Согласование).
Сами статусы хранятся в таблице Статус:

[image: Таблица Статус]

[image: Диаграмма БД]

```sql
SELECT
  Производитель.Производитель AS Производитель,
  Модель.Модель AS Модель,
  Клиенты.Фамилия AS Клиент,
  Сотрудники.Фамилия AS Сотрудник,
  MIN(Выполнение.Дата) AS Дата_приема
FROM Заявка
INNER JOIN Оборудование ON Заявка.Код_заявки = Оборудование.Код_заявки
JOIN Производитель ON Оборудование.Код_производителя = Производитель.Код_производителя
JOIN Модель ON Оборудование.Код_модели = Модель.Код_модели AND Оборудование.Код_производителя = Модель.Код_производителя
JOIN Клиенты ON Заявка.Код_клиента = Клиенты.Код_клиента
JOIN Сотрудники ON Заявка.Код_сотрудника=Сотрудники.Код_сотрудника
JOIN Выполнение ON Выполнение.Код_заявки=Заявка.Код_заявки
JOIN Статус ON Выполнение.Код_статуса=Статус.Код_статуса
GROUP BY
  Производитель.Производитель,
  Модель.Модель,
  Клиенты.Фамилия,
  Сотрудники.Фамилия
```

Comment: Вставьте запрос текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky не понимаю, зачем использовать оконную функцию, которая подсчитывает кол-во строк в группе.

Comment: `(PARTITION BY Код_заявки ORDER BY Дата DESC)` дает нам упорядоченные заявки для каждой группы, а seq = 1 является последней.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, извините, все равно не помогает, может что-то не так делаю, вставила итоговый запрос, и запрос на создание таблицы, но добавила выборку из таблицы Статус.Статус и все равно не получается

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, и не знаю как это можно показать, ибо картинка и код в комментариях не цепляются...

Comment: Я обновил свой ответ. Проверьте.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky да, я проверила, синтаксических ошибок нет, но я добавляю в выборку select Статус.Статус, чтобы получить именно последний статус, но тогда вылетает ошибка, что выборка Статус.Статус не возможна, тк не содержится в группировке. Добавляю в группировку, но тогда выводятся просто все строки и нет нужного результата

Comment: `MIN(Статус.Статус) AS Статус`

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, а нет, добавив WHERE вылетает синтаксическая ошибка "Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "WHERE".

Comment: Я обновил свой ответ. Проверьте. Это было неправильное место для `WHERE seq =1`

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky спасибо большое, получилось!

Comment: Рад слышать. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот концептуальный пример.

Он использует CTE для получения последнего статуса.

После этого просто используйте все свои JOINs, только вместо таблицы **Выполнение** используйте таблицу **rs** из CTE и добавьтe `WHERE seq = 1`.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и пример заполнения данных, начaло
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Код_заявки INT, Код_статуса INT, Дата DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl (Код_заявки, Код_статуса, Дата) VALUES
(1, 1 , '2021-11-18'),
(1, 2 , '2021-11-19'),
(1, 3 , '2021-11-20'),
(2, 1 , '2021-11-07'),
(2, 2 , '2021-11-09'),
(2, 4 , '2021-11-11'),
(2, 5 , '2021-11-12');
-- DDL и пример заполнения данных, конец

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
        , seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Код_заявки ORDER BY Дата DESC)
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * FROM rs
WHERE seq = 1;
```

**Результат**

```
+----+------------+-------------+------------+-----+
| ID | Код_заявки | Код_статуса |    Дата    | seq |
+----+------------+-------------+------------+-----+
|  3 |          1 |           3 | 2021-11-20 |   1 |
|  7 |          2 |           5 | 2021-11-12 |   1 |
+----+------------+-------------+------------+-----+
```

**Окончательный SQL**

```
;WITH rs AS
    (
        SELECT * 
            , seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Код_заявки ORDER BY Дата DESC)
        FROM Выполнение
    )
SELECT Производитель.Производитель AS Производитель,
  Модель.Модель AS Модель,
  Клиенты.Фамилия AS Клиент,
  Сотрудники.Фамилия AS Сотрудник,
  MIN(rs.Дата) AS Дата_приема
FROM Заявка
INNER JOIN Оборудование ON Заявка.Код_заявки = Оборудование.Код_заявки
JOIN Производитель ON Оборудование.Код_производителя = Производитель.Код_производителя
JOIN Модель ON Оборудование.Код_модели = Модель.Код_модели AND Оборудование.Код_производителя = Модель.Код_производителя
JOIN Клиенты ON Заявка.Код_клиента = Клиенты.Код_клиента
JOIN Сотрудники ON Заявка.Код_сотрудника=Сотрудники.Код_сотрудника
JOIN rs ON rs.Код_заявки=Заявка.Код_заявки
JOIN Статус ON rs.Код_статуса=Статус.Код_статуса
WHERE rs.seq = 1
GROUP BY
  Производитель.Производитель,
  Модель.Модель,
  Клиенты.Фамилия,
  Сотрудники.Фамилия;
```